# Orange app can't find MySQLdb. How do I install it?

Tags: python, pip, orange

I've installed the Orange app on my Mac and when I try a "Prototypes > SQL" widget, I get an error when executing the query. It says the MySQLdb Python library is not found/installed.

How do I go about installing it so that the Orange app can find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the optimal approach in terms of system paths and such, but it works.

Find where you installed Orange. If in the OS's Applications directory, it is:
/Applications/Orange.app

Try this at the console:

```
cd <your_Orange_app>/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/

./Python <your_Orange_app>/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip install MySQL-python
```

This just executes "pip install MySQL-python" but with the relevant python and the relevant pip.

Another approach might be to edit the `<your_Orange_app>/Contents/MacOS/ENV` file and specify the path to an existing installation of the MySQLdb lib.

Answer (score 0):

Using pip:

```
pip install MySQL-python
```